# How do I rename a form object (button, textbox, etc.) after Visual C# has autocreated the code?

Tags: c#, naming, visual-studio-exp-2013

Okay, so here's my problem: Whenever I create a button, textbox, listbox, then double-click to view the source code:

```
private void quitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

After this has been auto-created by Visual Studio, it won't allow me to change it later.

So when I go into properties and want to change "quitToolStripMenuItem" (in the Name property field) to "mnuQuit," it will show up in the properties window properly, and will change the name (for all intents and purposes), but when I double-click to view source - it still shows the 'quitToolStrip..." name.

If I rename it to

```
private void mnuQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

It will throw a big hissy fit, and then my form design will be gone and a (basically) 404 message will appear instead of the form.

How can I do it without deleting the item and then recreating?

Comment: When you rename there is a smart tag that pops up and let's you rename all references, you want to make sure to use that.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work unfortunately. 'The designer cannot process unknown name 'Name' at line 107. The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again.' -- is the error message and '404' message received any time I change it.

Comment: The way you have phrased the question, it sounds like you are double-clicking on a control as a way of switching from the design view to the source code view! I expect I have simply misunderstood what you are doing, but I thought I should just check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rename the event handler method, go to the designer, select the object (the menu item in your case), and in the properties window click the events button (it looks like a lightning bolt), and rename the event handler method from there.

In C#, the event handler is linked to the object that raise the event by a delegate, so the name of the method does not matter. You can have a button called `Jack` and event handler called `Jill_Click` that will actually handle the resize event of `Jack`. If you open the designer code you will see something like:

```
this.Jack.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Jill_Click);
```

Comment: Oh my, Thank you so much. This isn't the first time I ran into this issue. I just never asked because I hadn't ever put as much effort into setting the others up as I had this one and would just recreate them. LOL. Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just refactor the method name? This will update it on the `.designer.cs`, in your designer and of course in your code.

Select the method name, right click, *Refactor* → *Rename*.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? And perhaps edition (Express, Professional, Community, etc.). Is does not seem to be there in Visual Studio 2012 (yes, I know)

Comment: No idea man, this was back in '15 so I suppose this is VS2015

Answer (score 1):

Click on the *Events* (lightning) icon at the top of the *Properties* window and delete the text in the *Click* field.

Comment: If the original handler (function) is renamed first (in the .cs file), then this is a good way to ***avoid*** having to ***manually*** correct the name (unlike [Zohar Peled's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638776/how-do-i-rename-a-form-objectbutton-textbox-etc-after-visual-c-sharp-has-au/31638874#31638874)) - just double click on *"Click"*. (If it is not renamed then "`_1`" will be appended to the handler (function) name.)